# Polynomials producing Carmichael numbers

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

It is well known that $$(6n+1)(12n+1)(18n+1)$$ is a Carmichael number, if all factors are prime. I found the polynomials $$(6n+1)(12n+1)(18n+1)(36n+1)$$
$$(18n+1)(36n+1)(108n+1)(162n+1)$$ $$(20n+1)(80n+1)(100n+1)(200n+1)$$ $$(12n+1)(24n+1)(36n+1)(72n+1)(144n+1)$$

with the same property.

> Questions : Is there an efficient way to construct more such polynomials (without brute force) ?
>
> Does such a polynomial with degree $d$ exist for all $d\ge 3$ ?
>
> Besides the multiples of the vector $[6,12,18]$, does a vector $[a,b,c]$ 
>     exists, such that $(an+1)(bn+1)(cn+1)$ is such a polynomial ?

Comment: See [extended Chernick's Carmichael numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Carmichael_numbers#Extended_Chernick.27s_Carmichael_numbers) and [Carmichael polynomials from Egyptian fractions](http://11011110.livejournal.com/317501.html).

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you.